# Is key prefixing enough to satisfy multi-tenancy

Tags: database, redis

One of the solutions for multi-tenancy (e.g. multiple apps accessing the same Redis database while providing *isolation* from each other) is to implement *key prefixing*.

However, would it satisfy isolation for

- Query operations
- and search

As such any query (and search) from one application would not leak to the other application data.

Answer (score 0):

Try ACL in Redis 6.0, support limit of keys and operations for multi-tenancy.
https://redis.io/topics/acl